# How to bind Access database to DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datagridview, dataview

I'm new to C# and Visual Studio.
I'm working on a project that is searching through a database of information.

I want to bind a database (Microsoft access file) to my datagridview
but I want it to work with my preexisting code which utilizes a datatable converted into a dataview.

My database has a lot of information and I don't want to put it in manually. I've tried binding the information directly to the datagridview (through datasource in the properties) but then  searching doesn't work**. I've looked into sql but im trying to avoid learning 2 languages at the same time.

My projects basic functionality contains: 
1 combobox (idCbo) containing the search query's 
 1 datagridview for displaying the information

this setup is for searching one column only, im going to duplicate the code for the oher columns

The name of the column in the datagridview selects the column(id) for filtering then the combo box(idCbo) searches that column for matching characters in the datagridview and comboBox list.

the combo box contains the values 1-100 for searching the column

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
  
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataView dataView;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            dt.Rows.Add(i);


            dataView = new DataView(dt);
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataView;

            
        }

        private void idCbo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = idCbo.Text;
            dataView.RowFilter = $"convert(id,'System.String') LIKE '%{query}%'";
           
        }
}
```

**
Binding the database to the datagridview while using this code renders column titles but not the information and the code cannot access the database, columns or the rows System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot find column ...

***Big thanks to Johng for assisting me with the code :)*** 
***CURRENT WORKING CODE***

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static BindingSource gridBindingSource;

        private void idCbo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = idCbo.Text;
            gridBindingSource = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource;
            if (gridBindingSource != null)
            {
                if (query == "All")
                {
                    gridBindingSource.Filter = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    gridBindingSource.Filter = "convert(id,'System.String') LIKE '%" + query + "%'";
                }
            }
            
        }
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the '_InfoFinalv_2___CopyDataSet.Info' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            infoTableAdapter.Fill(this._InfoFinalv_2___CopyDataSet.Info);
            idCbo.Items.Add("All");
            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                idCbo.Items.Add(i);
            }
            idCbo.SelectedIndex = -1;

        }
        private void idReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            idCbo.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
```

Comment: Using `LIKE '%{query}%` with `string` “numbers” may not give you the results you are wanting. Example; selecting “1” will produce results with “1, 11, 12, 13, 14…21, 31, 41… etc”.

Comment: i have yet to find undesirable results from the LIKE '%{query}% 

all that line is doing is matching numbers from the combo box to the datagridview
and then excludes characters in-front and behind the query (this is the purpose of the % symbol) 

this prevents undesirable results like only numbers with 1 in the front 1 10 11 12 13 14 etc     or only 1 as the last character 1 11 21 31 41 51 etc

Comment: You state that... _"but then searching doesn't work."_ ... ? ... then what _"doesn't work"_?

Comment: i should probably be more clear on that. Binding the database to the datagridview while using this code renders column titles but not the information and the code cannot access the database, columns or the rows

System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot find column

Comment: when i change the column titles i get the same thing
even when i use the design name from the datagridview (iDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn)

Comment: _”Binding the database to the datagridview while using this code renders column titles but not the information and the code cannot access the database, columns or the rows”_ … ? … Where is the code that does this? The current posted code is creating its own `DataTable` and is setting it as the `DataSource` to the grid. Show the code you have as far as reading the data from the Access DB.

Comment: I was binding the database using the data source section in the properties menu of the datagridview.  i had used this way because i am unfamiliar with how to do it programatically

Comment: Well… if you state that… _”I was binding the database using the data source section in the properties menu of the datagridview.”_ … then… it would appear that this is not working either and you may need to do further research. I am just saying you give no code/examples of “how” you did this... so it would be pure speculation as to “why” it is not working.

Comment: I am just saying that if you set up the grids data source in the designer to use the Access DB… then “why” is the code setting the grids data source in the code you posted? The data you defined in the designer is getting overwritten by the posted code you have shown.

Comment: i was not aware that the designers and the code would work independently. i thought they worked on the same "layer" per se and would cooperate, which was the part giving me frustration

Comment: I am guilty of doing this in code and not using the designer, however, using the designer for this can be quite helpful and will write a lot of code for you automatically. Saving you time and debugging problems. I hope you have it working as you expect.

Comment: You check if the datagridview adds a data source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have set up the grids data source in the designer “correctly” then using the `DataView` as you want can be simplified by using the existing `BindingSource` that is usually created when you set up the grid’s data source in the designer.

We can use the existing grid’s `BindingSource` and then use it’s `Filter` property as opposed to converting the `BindingSource` to a `DataView` to filter. This will allow us to set the filter in the grid WITHOUT having to “change” the grids data source.

Remove all the code you have in the form constructor obviously leaving the `InitializeComponent();` and add the code below to the forms `Load` event. In the load event all we do is set up the combo box with the proper values. I added an “All” option to allow the user to “un-filter” the data in the grid.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet.EmployeeDT' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
  employeeDTTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.EmployeeDT); // <- created by the designer
  idCbo.Items.Add("All");
  for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    idCbo.Items.Add(i);
  }
  idCbo.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Then in the combo boxes `SelectedIndexChanged` event... change the code as shown below. Cast the grids `DataSource` to a `BindingSource` and then use its `Filter` property.

```
private void idCbo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string query = idCbo.Text;
  BindingSource GridBS = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource;
  if (GridBS != null) {
    if (query == "All") {
      GridBS.Filter = "";
    }
    else {
      GridBS.Filter = "EmpID LIKE '%" + query + "%'";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so i ran into a few errors on my end but i got it working
i changed `GridBS.Filter = "EmpID LIKE '%" + query + "%'";` to 
`gridBindingSource.Filter = "convert(id,'System.String') LIKE '%" + query + "%'";` because of a cannot perform like on system int and string error and then i changed `idCbo.SelectedIndex = 0;` to `-1`. i also put gridviewBindingSource into public static and changed `BindingSource GridBS = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource;` to `gridBindingSource = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource;`  current code is now in my post at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Here's the tip:

On the form load, make an ajax call to the database and fetch only the required data columns. Return data will be in JSON that can be used as data for DataTable.

I used it in an MVC project recently and it works fine. If you would like I can share the detailed code and logic.

Not sharing the code since I'm not sure if you are on .Net MVC.

Comment: i dont think i am
 I started the project as a winforms .net framework